# software to unify css files

Tags: css, optimization, stylesheet

lets say in

**a.css** (first .css) i have

```
body{ background: yellow}
p { color: blue}
span { background : red}
h2{ color:orange}
```

**b.css** (second .css) i have

```
body{ background: red}
p { color: blue}
span { background : black}
h1{ font-weight:bold}
```

**c.css** (a+b.css) *should have*

```
body{ background: red}
p { color: blue}
span { background : black}
h1{ font-weight:bold}
h2{ color:orange}
```

Very simple. basically c.css gets a.css and b.css and overrides all the properties existing  in a.css and b.css,

This task was easy but what if we have .css files with thousands of lines? is there any software that will aoutomat this task?

Comment: Many CSS minifiers can do this. For example this site I quickly found on Google can do it: http://www.csscompressor.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at http://www.cssoptimiser.com/?

-- EDIT --

http://iceyboard.no-ip.org/projects/css_compressor  generates:

`h2{color:orange}body{background:red}p{color:blue}span{background:black}h1{font-weight:700}`

which matches your expected output.

Comment: this is what it would generate: body{background:yellow}p,p,p{color:blue}span,body,body{background:red}h2,h2{color:orange}span,span{background:black}h1,h1{font-weight:bold}  it doesn't look like what i need

Comment: Added another link. My point was that there are a bunch of online tools available for this.